Dynamic Auto fill pivot column fields in BelongsToMany relationship between resources
I have two models product and contracts, both has many to many relationship
Product has 2 fields, name and price
Models -
Product.php
public function contracts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contract::class, 'contract_products')
            ->withPivot('contract_price', 'quantity');
    }

Contract.php
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'contract_products')
            ->withPivot('contract_price', 'quantity');
    }

in Nova resource:
Contract.php
BelongsToMany::make('Products', 'products', Products::class)
                ->fields(function () {
                    return [
                        Currency::make('Contract Price'),
                        Number::make('Quantity')->nullable(),
                    ];
                }),

when we attach product to contract in Nova resource, I see 4 fields, one is the Contract name, which is not editable, second is a dropdown of the available products displaying its name, third is contract price,
How to autofill the Pivot column contract_price with the product price dynamically, when the product is selected from second dropdown field.
as I see, fields won't automatically update without a page reload. Nova doesn't natively support dynamic field population out of the box

You can use the dependsOn field to change the value based off the selected product dynamically:
use App\Models\Product as ProductModel;
BelongsToMany::make('Products', 'products', Products::class)
    ->fields(function () {
        return [
            Currency::make('Contract Price')
                ->dependsOn(['products'], function (Currency $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
                  $selectedProductId = $formData->products;
                  if ($selectedProductId) {
                      $product = ProductModel::find($selectedProductId);
                      $field->value = $product->price;
                  }
           }),
        ];
   }),


